# Efficient Method for Uniform Sampling from the Space of Increasing Vectors in $[0, 1]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-walk, sampling, sampling-theory

I am seeking advice on methods for uniformly sampling from the space of increasing vectors within the interval $[0, 1]$. Specifically, I require an efficient algorithm that can handle high-dimensional vectors (e.g., dimensionality around 100), where each vector component satisfies $0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \ldots \leq x_{100} \leq 1$.

I have attempted to use the hit-and-run sampling technique, applying linear constraints to ensure the monotonicity of the vector components. However, I've observed that this approach tends to converge very slowly in high dimensions and stay close to the initial guess

Does anyone have suggestions for alternative methods for uniform sampling?
Thanks!

Comment: I think sampling $100$ numbers uniformly at random from $[0,1]$ and then sorting them should give you the required sample.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion! unfortunately, it seems not to achieve a uniform distribution across the space of increasing vectors. To see this, consider the distribution of the first component of the vector, which essentially represents the minimum value of n draws from uniform dist. The likelihood of this component being a large number is significantly lower compared to it being a smaller number. This suggests that there's a greater probability of drawing a vector that begins with a lower value rather than those that start higher up and therefore the implied distribution is not uniform

Comment: For simplicity of discussion consider a $2$-D scenario and consider the region $x_1 \leq x_2$. If you are picking a sample uniformly at random from this region (that is what I understand from a sample being "uniform"), then note that you are indeed more likely to pick a point with lower value of $x_1$ as the marginal density of $x_1$ is non-uniform. You can easily see that the density of $x_1$ is skewed with smaller values corresponding to higher density values.

Comment: Now, if by "uniform" you meant to say that the marginal distributions of _each coordinate_ is "uniform" then it implies that the sampling is "not uniform from the region $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \dots \leq x_{100}$". In this case, I am not sure if such a density is even possible but an option would be to sample $x_i$ from $[x_{i-1}, 1]$ with $x_0 = 0$ for $i \geq 1$.